# Strange journal behavior in incremental backups

Tags: server, systemd-journald

From some time I observe a strange behavior of my journal logs in my incremental backup. Let's, for example, take the last seven days:

```
RychuSrvSystemBackup_2019-03-14_060001.tar.gz     570.26 MB     2019-03-14 06:00:08
RychuSrvSystemBackup_2019-03-15_060001.tar.gz     63.37 MB      2019-03-15 06:00:08
RychuSrvSystemBackup_2019-03-16_060001.tar.gz     572.26 MB     2019-03-16 06:00:08
RychuSrvSystemBackup_2019-03-17_060001.tar.gz     56.74 MB      2019-03-17 06:00:08
RychuSrvSystemBackup_2019-03-18_060002.tar.gz     575.14 MB     2019-03-18 06:00:08
RychuSrvSystemBackup_2019-03-19_060001.tar.gz     57.26 MB      2019-03-19 06:00:08
RychuSrvSystemBackup_2019-03-20_060001.tar.gz     577.64 MB     2019-03-20 06:00:08
```

As you can see the pattern is clearly visible. Every second incremental backup is 10 times bigger than the previous one.

Most of the content of the bigger ones is occupied by journal:
[image: journal files take 92% of backup]

But if I run `sudo journalctl -b 0` to see the log for current boot then it isn't long. For sure not for 4GB long. Below you can see that 10 days of the current journal contains 2 448 552 characters and separate days aren't very different:

```
rychu@RychuSRV:~$ date
Wed Mar 20 21:41:59 CET 2019
rychu@RychuSRV:~$ uptime
 21:42:03 up 10 days, 23 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.06, 0.03, 0.00
rychu@RychuSRV:~$ sudo journalctl -b 0 --all | wc
  23754  303844 2448552
rychu@RychuSRV:~$ sudo journalctl -b 0 --since "2019-03-15" --until "2019-03-16" | wc --bytes
227629
rychu@RychuSRV:~$ sudo journalctl -b 0 --since "2019-03-16" --until "2019-03-17" | wc --bytes
225997
rychu@RychuSRV:~$ sudo journalctl -b 0 --since "2019-03-17" --until "2019-03-18" | wc --bytes
219993
rychu@RychuSRV:~$ sudo journalctl -b 0 --since "2019-03-18" --until "2019-03-19" | wc --bytes
218366
```

Can anyone please explain to me what am I looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened one of the backup files and investigated it. The journal files contained logs from October. So I went to my journal logs folder to check what is going on there. For some reason, it contained a lot of old files.

```
rychu@RychuSRV:/var/log/journal/49c3cfc239cf43ba92e578f070ce35cb$ ls -1lt
total 936272
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Mar 26 21:40 system.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Mar 26 21:40 user-1000.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  25165824 Mar 26 21:40 system@6b32fcbe244e46c8a49b4a12b888f330-0000000000467dd7-0005849ff9c719fc.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Mar 26 21:40 user-1000@85073486393d48dfa71d4b44fc06a986-000000000045b25d-000583bb822d1769.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  50331648 Mar 21 20:45 system@6b32fcbe244e46c8a49b4a12b888f330-000000000045c780-000583bcf695c289.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Mar 10 13:54 system@6b32fcbe244e46c8a49b4a12b888f330-000000000045b268-000583bb822eeba9.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Mar 10 12:10 system@6b32fcbe244e46c8a49b4a12b888f330-000000000045a9b8-000583a964b2114a.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Mar 10 12:10 user-1000@85073486393d48dfa71d4b44fc06a986-000000000042a1b5-000581542ff460ad.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  92274688 Mar  9 14:34 system@6b32fcbe244e46c8a49b4a12b888f330-000000000043b7f4-0005821a2d1d6896.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  25165824 Feb 17 18:17 system@6b32fcbe244e46c8a49b4a12b888f330-0000000000434fd1-00058209bff09636.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  33554432 Feb 16 22:41 system@6b32fcbe244e46c8a49b4a12b888f330-000000000042a1c0-000581542ff60fa7.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  75497472 Feb  7 22:04 system@6b32fcbe244e46c8a49b4a12b888f330-000000000041291d-0005805bb9b54dde.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Feb  5 22:51 user-1000@85073486393d48dfa71d4b44fc06a986-00000000003f2803-00057ecaa2138ad0.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  92274688 Jan 26 13:38 system@6b32fcbe244e46c8a49b4a12b888f330-00000000003f280e-00057ecaa21549c9.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  75497472 Jan  6 15:07 system@6b32fcbe244e46c8a49b4a12b888f330-00000000003d78ea-00057d741dcd13d8.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Dec 30 16:44 user-1000@85073486393d48dfa71d4b44fc06a986-00000000003b607b-00057c0971f6aa02.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  92274688 Dec 20 14:29 system@6b32fcbe244e46c8a49b4a12b888f330-00000000003b6772-00057c097595426a.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Dec  2 13:49 system@6b32fcbe244e46c8a49b4a12b888f330-00000000003b6022-00057c0971f2ac17.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 100663296 Dec  2 13:48 system@6b32fcbe244e46c8a49b4a12b888f330-0000000000000001-00057a75254c56a7.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Dec  2 13:22 user-1000@85073486393d48dfa71d4b44fc06a986-00000000003b04c0-00057bd1e273d8d8.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Nov 12 11:27 system@00057a7525512690-a01fba17046f297f.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 109051904 Nov 11 09:59 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-0000000000391369-0005798636e53ebc.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Nov  8 08:08 user-1000@85073486393d48dfa71d4b44fc06a986-00000000003a2031-00057986ae4b8fe1.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:23 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-0000000000369dcc-00057986363f6125.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:23 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-0000000000342299-00057986356c935d.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:23 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000031bce4-0005798634c62dfd.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:23 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-00000000002f49dd-00057986341380c5.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:23 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-00000000002cd580-000579863361e27a.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:22 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-00000000002a5f66-0005798632b3049d.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:22 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000027ec56-000579863207f641.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:22 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000025752d-000579863166eb35.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:22 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000022fcf1-0005798630c4b710.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:22 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-0000000000208466-00057986301980e0.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:22 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-00000000001e0e79-000579862f79aa69.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:21 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-00000000001b89de-000579862ebbe63a.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:21 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-00000000001919f1-000579862dea0fea.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:21 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000016a2f2-000579862d1dc5b1.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:21 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-0000000000142758-000579862c3b1988.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:20 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000011b41e-000579862b4cfb05.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:20 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-00000000000f3947-000579862a623523.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:20 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-00000000000cc4af-00057986294bd0b0.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 134217728 Oct 31 14:20 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-00000000000a5ec6-000579727fa017a2.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Oct 31 14:01 user-1000@85073486393d48dfa71d4b44fc06a986-0000000000087eba-00057834554d497e.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  67108864 Oct 30 14:52 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000008fbb4-0005786de88cc8e4.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  33554432 Oct 17 16:58 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-0000000000087ec5-00057834554ec4d2.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  75497472 Oct 14 20:17 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000006e799-000576eb9431c0e4.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Sep 30 14:32 user-1000@85073486393d48dfa71d4b44fc06a986-0000000000067f69-00057586adfd2a7b.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  50331648 Sep 28 12:04 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000005c240-000574e7d0ff8277.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 100663296 Sep  2  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-0000000000036449-000573a34107c409.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Aug 30  2018 user-1000@85073486393d48dfa71d4b44fc06a986-000000000003643a-000573a341065e3c.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  25165824 Aug 17  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000002ebe9-0005732644727647.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Aug 16  2018 user-1000@85073486393d48dfa71d4b44fc06a986-000000000001db6f-00057134e41e02a8.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Aug 11  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000002e46f-00057326338a8233.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Aug 11  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000002d8c2-0005728409020411.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  25165824 Aug  3  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-0000000000027e27-000571eb4585d762.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Jul 26  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-0000000000027658-000571adbec89b2f.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  16777216 Jul 23  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-00000000000242d4-0005715f22ee8579.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  25165824 Jul 19  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000001db7e-00057134e41f6c6c.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Jul 17  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000001daf6-00057134b772aff4.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Jul 17  2018 user-1000@85073486393d48dfa71d4b44fc06a986-0000000000001d22-00056ec1cd44e38d.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  16777216 Jul 17  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-00000000000199ff-0005706479e88b1a.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Jul  7  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-00000000000192db-00057032808fb00a.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Jul  4  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000001881f-00057032038d82b4.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Jul  4  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000001818a-000570316124cd44.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Jul  4  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-0000000000017c40-0005700a4b518857.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  25165824 Jul  2  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000001107a-00056fb4f9f4a1fb.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  16777216 Jun 28  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000000e552-00056fb115f8a63a.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  16777216 Jun 28  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000000baf5-00056f7ddd5bc201.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Jun 25  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-000000000000ab93-00056f7cc22f704d.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  16777216 Jun 25  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-0000000000007db7-00056f2b405ada63.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  16777216 Jun 21  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-0000000000004bc1-00056eefbd243da3.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  16777216 Jun 18  2018 system@0a34594fa6cf47028146717661072913-0000000000000001-00056ebf5f41359d.journal
```

I cleared these files using

```
rychu@RychuSRV:/var/log/journal/49c3cfc239cf43ba92e578f070ce35cb$ sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=1m
```

So there were only the latest files left

```
rychu@RychuSRV:/var/log/journal/49c3cfc239cf43ba92e578f070ce35cb$ ls -1lt
total 149
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 8388608 Mar 26 21:42 system.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 8388608 Mar 26 21:40 user-1000.journal
```

Unfortunatly I can't explain why `tar` had seen these files touched and included them in the backup nor why they hadn't been cleared by `logrotate` but since this time the strange behavior has been gone and all my incr. backups are small again! :)